# meter al hacer click en diferents botones valores en una matriz

Tags: javascript

estoy intntando cada vez que hag click en unos bototes, meter en una matriz que estaba vacia , meter en la al hacer click unos valores, pero resulta que hago la prueba para ver si se ha llenado la matriz y resulta que no me ha llenado nada , porque me sale undefined
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
</head>
<body>
   
    <input type="text" id="salidatotal" ></input>
    <button id="uno" onclick="salidauno()">1</button>
    <button id="dos" onclick="salidados()">2</button>
    <button id="tres" onclick="salidatres()">3</button>
    <button id="sumaok" onclick="salida();sumaokok();operacion()">+</button>
    <button id="resta" onclick="salida();resta();operacion()">-</button>
    <button id="multiplicacion" onclick="salida();multiplicacion();operacion()">*</button>
    <button id="division" onclick="salida();operacion()">/</button>
    <button id="resultadook" onclick="resultado()">=</button>
    <button onclick="prueba()">prueba</button>



  <script>

        //Declaramos variables

        numero=0;
        suma=[];
        i=0;
        total=suma[0];
        caso=0;
        numerook=0;
     

        function salidauno()

        {
            numero=numero+document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("salidatotal").value=numero;
           
        }
        function salidados()

            {
                numero=numero+document.getElementById("dos").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("salidatotal").value=numero;
               
            }
            function salidatres()

            {
                numero=numero+document.getElementById("tres").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("salidatotal").value=numero;
               
            }

           

            function salida(suma){
                
                
               document.getElementById("salidatotal").value="";
               numerook= 5;
               suma[i]=numerook;
               
               numero="";
               i++;
          
              
                                                                 
                                                    
            }
            function prueba(){
                for(i=0;i<suma.lenght;i++){

                    alert(suma[i])
                }
            }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno algo que podría ser es que las variables se declaran con const,let o var.

```
 //Declaramos variables

    let numero=0;
    var suma=[];
    let i=0;
```

Y también para que no caigas en la trampa de la concatenación en vez de:

```
numero=numero+document.getElementById("tres").innerHTML;
```

usa :

```
numero=numero+parseInt(document.getElementById("tres").innerHTML);
```

pues así conviertes el valor a entero y así hace la suma, sin embargo si solo dejas el signo + entonces va a concatenar el valor.

Answer (score 1):

Te proporciono lo siguiente con algunos comentario; lo que te esta fallando es tu lógica en el procesamiento de los datos; así como al parecer el ámbito (local y/o Global) del mismo.

```js
var numero='';
var suma=[];
var i=0;
var total=suma[0]; /* Para este momento el elemento 0 no existe */
var caso=0;
var numerook=0;

// El siguiente reemplaza tus "salidauno", "salidados" y "salidatres"
function agregarNumero(obj) {
  numero=numero+document.getElementById(obj.id).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value=numero;
} // agregarNumero

function salida(/*suma*/){
  // El parámetro suma que envias ¿para que? no tiene razon de ser
  // ya que en  las llamadas a función "salida" no lo pasas su valor siempre es "undefined".
  document.getElementById("salidatotal").value="";
  numerook= 5; // Solo aquí le asignas valor
  suma.push(numerook); // Prefiero usar push
  //suma[i]=numerook; // Para tu caso siempre la agregas 5
               
  numero="";
  i++;
}

function prueba(){
  console.log(suma); // Yo prefiero console para ver todos los valores
  /*
  // No uses i por que es global y la estas usando en otras partes.
  var j=0;
  for(j=0;j<suma.length;j++){
    alert(suma[j]);
  }*/
} // prueba
```

```html
<input type="text" id="salidatotal" /> <!-- el cierre de input no es </input> -->
    <button id="uno" onclick="agregarNumero(this)">1</button>
    <button id="dos" onclick="agregarNumero(this)">2</button>
    <button id="tres" onclick="agregarNumero(this)">3</button>
    <button id="sumaok" onclick="salida();/*sumaokok();operacion()*/">+</button>
    <button id="resta" onclick="salida();/*resta();operacion()*/">-</button>
    <button id="multiplicacion" onclick="salida();/*multiplicacion();operacion()*/">*</button>
    <button id="division" onclick="salida();/*operacion()*/">/</button>
    <button id="resultadook" onclick="resultado()">=</button>
    <button onclick="prueba()">prueba</button>
```